# Backspace deletes a whole word zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm currently having a minor issue with zsh, as since the last update, pressing backspace deletes a whole word, which is quite inconvenient. I looked for a solution, thought it may come from a sneaky use of the widget backward-kill-word, but it appears not. So here i am, stuck.
Btw, i use oh-my-zsh.

Thanks !

Edit : Zsh is on its 5.8 version, and i'm running archlinux (should have iuncluded it in OP, sorry)
Indeed, when typing the suggested command, it appears that backsapce is bing to backward-kill-word

Edit : Got it, i rebinded backspace to backward-delete-char, but it doesn't seem to be persistent, even when put in my zshrc

Edit : As requested, here is the output of stty -a

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 47; columns 173; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Comment: What command line editing mode are you in? Emacs or Vi?

Comment: Standard one, so emacs

Comment: Type `bindkey ''`, put the cursor between the quotes, press Ctrl+V then Backspace. What is inserted on the command line? Run this command. What's the output? Do you have the same problem with `zsh -f` ? With `ZDOTDIR=/none zsh` ? What version of zsh is this, on what operating system, and in what terminal?

Comment: You should also put the output of `stty -a` into the question.